# Dynamically resize a JTextField and set minimum amount of text

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, layout-manager

I would like to dynamically resize a `JTextField` and also set a minimum amount of text allowed.

### Example

The text field can have a minimum length of 4, if the text is less than 4 add 0 for every slot missing.

Comment: *"if the text is less than 4 add 0"*  Seems like a `JSpinner` with a `SpinnerNumberModel` might be better for this.

Comment: try using a `JFormattedTextField`. for more information, see [How to Use Formatted Text Fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html).

Answer (score 0):

Below there is an example of such JTextField:

```
public class TextField extends JTextField {
    public static final int TEXT_FIELD_PADDING = 4;

    public TextField() {
        addAutoResize();
        init();
    }

    public void init() {
        setStyleByParentStyle();
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(Constant.
TEXT_FIELD_MINIMAL_WIDTH, this.getPreferredSize().height));
    }

    private void addAutoResize() {
        this.getDocument().addDocumentListener
(new DocumentListener() {
            @Override
            public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            checkResize();
            }

            @Override
            public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            checkResize();
            }

            @Override
            public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            checkResize();
            }
        });
    }

    private void checkResize() {
        FontMetrics fontMetrics = this.getFontMetrics(this.
getFont());

        if (fontMetrics.stringWidth(this.getText()) + 
TEXT_FIELD_PADDING * 2 < Constant.TEXT_FIELD_MINIMAL_WIDTH) {
            this.setPreferredSize(new 
Dimension(Constant.TEXT_FIELD_MINIMAL_WIDTH, this.getHeight()));
            this.getParent().revalidate();
        } else {
            //NOTE 2 - border width*2
            this.setPreferredSize(new 
Dimension(fontMetrics.stringWidth(this.getText()) + 2 + 
Constant.CARRET_WIDTH + TEXT_FIELD_PADDING * 2, this.getHeight()));
            this.getParent().revalidate();
        }
    }
}
```

This information is taken from the article:
[Frequently Asked Questions during Java applet development](http://jazzteam.org/en/technical-articles/frequently-asked-questions-during-java-applet-development/)